# Error in AdRotator Control

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am very new to ASP.NET and I am still learning the basics and how to use various controls. 
I have used the adRotator control and also created the XML File using the coding mentioned below, but when executed in the browser it is showing error message(Which I am posting after the code)

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Advertisement>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl> images/Logo.gif</ImageUrl>
    <NavigateUrl>http://www.google.co.in</NavigateUrl>
    <AlternateTExt> Main </AlternateTExt>
    <Keyword>LogoImage</Keyword>
  </Ad>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl> images/RedBik.gif</ImageUrl>
    <NavigateUrl>http://www.yahoo.co.in</NavigateUrl>
    <AlternateTExt> Main2 </AlternateTExt>
    <Keyword>RedBikImage</Keyword>
  </Ad>
</Advertisement>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:AdRotator id="AdRotator1" 
            style="Z-INDEX: 102; LEFT: 32px; 
        POSITION: absolute; TOP: 32px; height: 222px; width: 883px;" 
            runat="server" AdvertisementFile="~/myAds.xml">

    </asp:AdRotator>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I have not written any coding in the file Default.aspx.cs.
The ERROR MESSAGE I am getting in the browser is:

**Server Error in '/AdRotatorControl' Application.
 Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.
Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".**

Web.Config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can any one identify the error and please help me out?

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your web.config file to enable detailed error messages, to do so, add this tag to your web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: Remembering to to turn it back on before you deploy to prod!